# React Native - Disable Sign In button when the inputs are empty

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-native

So I just created a sign in / sign up form in my react native app.

It look like this:

[image]

I want the "Sign In" button disabled till the Username and Password inputs are filled up.

The "Sign In" Button should look black when inputs are empty, and when we fill up the input then the "Sign In" button should look blue.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    StyleSheet,
    Platform,
    TextInput,
    StatusBar,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Button
} from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome, { SolidIcons, RegularIcons, BrandIcons } from 'react-native-fontawesome';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
        check_textInputChange: false,
        secureTextEntry: true,
    });

    const handlePasswordChange = (val) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            password: val
        })
    }

    const updateSecureTextEntry = () => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry
        });
    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor='#428df5' barStyle="light-content"/>
            <Animatable.View style={styles.header} animation="fadeInDownBig">
            <Text style={styles.text_header}>Sign in to your Account!</Text>
            </Animatable.View>

            <Animatable.View 
             style={styles.footer}
             animation="fadeInUpBig">
            <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Username</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <TextInput 
                placeholder="Your Username"
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCapitalize = "none"
                />
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.text_footer, {
                marginTop: 35,
                fontSize: 18
            }}>Password</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <TextInput 
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCapitalize = "none"
                onChangeText={(val) => handlePasswordChange(val)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={updateSecureTextEntry}
                >
                    {data.secureTextEntry ? 
                <Text>
                    Show
                </Text>
                :
                <Text>
                    Hide
                </Text>}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.button}>
            <LinearGradient
                    colors={['#7aaef5', '#428df5']}
                    style={styles.signIn}
                >
                    <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                        color:'#fff'
                    }]}>Sign In</Text>
            </LinearGradient>

            <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')}
                    style={[styles.signIn, {
                        borderColor: '#428df5',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        marginTop: 15
                    }]}
                >
                    <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                        color: '#428df5'
                    }]}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default SignInScreen;
```

Kindly Help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `useMemo` to derive a new value called `isFormValid` and use it to conditionally apply styles and the `disabled` prop.

```js
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        username: "",
        password: "",
        check_textInputChange: false,
        secureTextEntry: true,
    });

    const handlePasswordChange = (val) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            password: val,
        });
    };

    const updateSecureTextEntry = () => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry,
        });
    };

    const isFormValid = useMemo(() => {
        return data.username.length > 0 && data.password.length > 0;
    }, [data.username, data.password]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#428df5" barStyle="light-content" />
            <Animatable.View style={styles.header} animation="fadeInDownBig">
                <Text style={styles.text_header}>Sign in to your Account!</Text>
            </Animatable.View>

            <Animatable.View style={styles.footer} animation="fadeInUpBig">
                <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Username</Text>
                <View style={styles.action}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Your Username"
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                    />
                </View>

                <Text
                    style={[
                        styles.text_footer,
                        {
                            marginTop: 35,
                            fontSize: 18,
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    Password
                </Text>

                <View style={styles.action}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(val) => handlePasswordChange(val)}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateSecureTextEntry}>
                        {data.secureTextEntry ? (
                            <Text>Show</Text>
                        ) : (
                            <Text>Hide</Text>
                        )}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <LinearGradient
                        colors={["#7aaef5", "#428df5"]}
                        style={styles.signIn}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={[
                                styles.textSign,
                                {
                                    color: "#fff",
                                },
                            ]}
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </Text>
                    </LinearGradient>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        disabled={!isFormValid}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignUpScreen")}
                        style={[
                            styles.signIn,
                            !isFormValid &&
                                {
                                    // Your disabled styles
                                },
                            {
                                borderColor: "#428df5",
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                marginTop: 15,
                            },
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={[
                                styles.textSign,
                                {
                                    color: "#428df5",
                                },
                            ]}
                        >
                            Sign Up
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default SignInScreen;
```